# Trying to round a number to 2 decimal places in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, rounding

Im trying to group some data from a MySQL table, using round to convert values to 2 decimal places.

[image: database]

As you can see in the previous picture the round of 15.625 to 2 decimals should be 15.63, but it doesnt work.

Im using the following query:

```
SELECT total, ROUND(total, 2) AS rounded FROM `project`
```

¿Can anyone give me some clue about what is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its gives 15.63 check here https://dbfiddle.uk/4r1UAq7h .. which version of mysql qre you using ?

Comment: *... it doesnt work.* provides absolutely no information about the issue: whether you have an error or the result is incorrect. Please add sample data and your current output or post an error message you have

Comment: Is total a float datatype? If not what is it? https://dbfiddle.uk/iGQ3R8Nl

Comment: Just found where the issue is thanks to the @P.Salmon comments. The column is VARCHAR(50). Rounding in VARCHAR gives the 15.62, if I change to float it works. Thanks!